# Dibujar Octogono con Python

Tags: python

Estaba intentando dibujar un octógono para un trabajo en el que me piden recrear varios elementos estructurales. El lado se consigue a través de la expresión `L = 2 * r * sin(pi/8)`.
He intentado de muchas formas y la que más se ha acercado es la siguiente pero sigo teniendo algún error que soy incapaz de encontrar:

```
from math import sin, pi

def strel(texto,r):
    if texto == 'octagon':
        octogon = [linea_octagon(k,r) for k in range(2*r+1)]
    return octogon

def linea_octagon(linea_octogono,r):
    L = round(2*r*sin(pi/8))
    linea =[]
    if linea_octogono <= r - L/2:
        linea.extend(0 for i in range(round(r-L/2 - linea_octogono)))
        linea.extend(1 for i in range(round(L/2 + linea_octogono)))
        linea.extend(1 for i in range(round(L/2 + linea_octogono)))
        linea.extend(0 for i in range(round(r-L/2 - linea_octogono)))

    if linea_octogono> r-L/2 and linea_octogono<r+L/2-1:
        linea.extend(1 for i in range(round(2*r)))

    if linea_octogono>=r+L/2-1:
        linea.extend(0 for i in range(1+round(linea_octogono - (r+L/2))))
        linea.extend(1 for i in range(-1+round(r - (linea_octogono - (r+L/2)))))
        linea.extend(1 for i in range(-1+round(r - (linea_octogono - (r+L/2)))))
        linea.extend(0 for i in range(1+round(linea_octogono - (r+L/2))))
    
    return linea
```

Cualquier ayuda es bien recibida, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido! hay dos variables que no están definidas `sin` y `pi`, también falta el ver como estás lanzando el código. Por favor puedes agregar esto a tu pregunta para que sea un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)